# React Redux App - statement after dispatches do not always work

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

In my react app, I am trying to accept the user information and build some local objects and then navigate to some url.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    handleLogin: (userName, password) => {
      dispatch(login(userName, password)).then(
        (response) => {
          if(!response.error){ 
            dispatch(buildProfile(response.payload.data)); 
            browserHistory.push('/'); // <-- This does not work in the first call to handleLogin and always works in the second call
          }
          else{
            dispatch(loginFailed(response.payload));
          }
        });
      }
    };
  };
```

The line `browserHistory.push('/');` never gets called first time I click login button, though the buildProfile returns successfully. Only when I click login next time, redirection happens. What could be going wrong? And  this happens consistently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors/warnings in your browser console?

Comment: No. I debugged the same as well. The browserHistory statement just does not get executed.

Comment: @Timo, Thanks for the hint. Yes indeed there was an error in my JSX, which was crashing during render after the first dispatch statement. After I fixed that, it has started working.

Answer (score 0):

There was a null variable access in my JSX (not posted here) which was crashing in response to the state update after first dispatch. After fixing that, this works as desired.